# select is not finishing after choosing an option

Tags: bash, select, couchpotato

I am working on a script to back up my CouchPotatoServer, but I'm having problems.

Here is the code I am having problems with:

```
select OPTION in Backup Restore Finish; do
    echo "You choose $OPTION CouchPotatoServer settings";
    case $OPTION in
        Backup)
            echo "Backing up settings file to $CPBPATH:";
            cp $CPSPATH/settings.conf $CPBPATH/settings-"$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M)".bak ;
            echo "Done!"
            break
            ;;
        Restore)
            echo "Please choose a backup to restore settings" ;
            AVAILABLEFILES="($(find $CPBPATH -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0))"
            select FILE in $AVAILABLEFILES; do
                cp "$FILE" $CPSPATH/settings.conf ;
                echo "restored $FILE"
                break
                ;;
done
```

The problem is that after the user chooses one option and the code is executed, it keeps waiting for a new selection, but I want it to exit. How can I do that?

Comment: You're missing the `esac` to close the `case` statement.

Answer (score 1):

`break` exits a loop, but you have nested loops and get stuck in the outer one. `break` actually takes an argument to specify how many enclosing loops you want to exit, so when you replace your `break` with `break 2`, you'll also exit the outer `select` loop.

Here is a little script to demonstrate the different `break` levels in `select` statements:

```
#!/bin/bash

PS3="Outer selection: "
select option1 in outer1 outer2 ; do
    echo "option1 is $option1"
    PS3="Inner selection: "
    case "$option1" in
        outer1)
            select option2 in inner1 inner2; do
                echo "option2 is $option2, issuing 'break'"
                PS3="Outer selection: "
                break
            done
            ;;
        outer2)
            select option2 in inner3 inner4; do
                echo "option2 is $option2, issuing 'break 2'"
                break 2
            done
            ;;
    esac
done
```

`PS3` is the prompt shown when using the `select` statement. As long as the outer option is `outer1`, you'll loop back to the outer `select` because only a single `break` is issued; if you select `outer2`, you'll exit the program with `break 2`.